# Twilio - Advanced opt-out feature not listed in Copilot features list

Tags: twilio

For some reason the messaging features doesn't list the "Advanced Opt-out" feature in our account.  Is there an account configuration that could make it visible?

Here is the screen shot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible there is a flag on your account which would conflict with the Advanced Opt-Out functionality, for example if you are programmatically handling the opt-out list on your side. You should open a support ticket with Twilio and provide then your Account SID. They should be able to investigate further.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I did go to Twilio support and they told that the "Stop Filtering" was disabled on my account and only they can enable it.  Once they enabled it, the "Opt-out" feature came back on the list.